# JMeter test script is getting struck while running the script in GUI and Non GUI mode

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

JMeter test script is getting struck while running the script in GUI and Non-GUI mode.

1. I have recorded the script in our QA env and executed the script in JMeter it is working fine all scenarios.
2. But when I recorded the script in other performance test environment(Load balancing server with VM's enabled ) but in this Environment, I am not able to execute all scenarios, here in the middle of the scenario it is getting struck.

Please help here, how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

your "getting struck" doesn't tell anything to us, you need to supply more troubleshooting information like:

- [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)
- [JMeter log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- Thread dump which can be taken from JMeter GUI or using [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html)

  [image]

For the time being I can give only a generic piece of advice: by default JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers don't have any connect/response timeouts defined so it's up to underlying JVM and/or operating system when to close the connection so make sure to provide reasonable timeout values, the setting lives at "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or better use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so the setting will be propagated to all HTTP Request samplers so you won't have to change it for each sampler individually)

[image]